# How to get COM object for embedded IE browser?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, winapi, watir, win32ole

How to translate this function from AutoIt's IE.au3 UDF to Ruby? Intention is to use Watir with an Internet Explorer browser (embedded in another application).

The AutoIt function works fine but I prefer Watir (which is Ruby). I can get the handle of the embedded browser using `ControlGetHandle()`, which is not available from the AutoIt dll.

Below is the function to translate (also 2 others which I don't need).

```
;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    __IEControlGetObjFromHWND()
; Description:      Returns a COM Object Window reference to an embebedded Webbrowser control
; Parameter(s):     $hWin       - HWND of a Internet Explorer_Server1 control obtained for example:
;                   $hwnd = ControlGetHandle("MyApp","","Internet Explorer_Server1")
; Requirement(s):   Windows XP, Windows 2003 or higher.
;                   Windows 2000; Windows 98; Windows ME; Windows NT may install the
;                   Microsoft Active Accessibility 2.0 Redistributable:
;                   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9B14F6E1-888A-4F1D-B1A1-DA08EE4077DF&displaylang=en
; Return Value(s):  On Success  - Returns DOM Window object
;                   On Failure  - 0  and sets @ERROR = 1
; Author(s):        Larry with thanks to Valik
;
;===============================================================================

Func __IEControlGetObjFromHWND(ByRef $hWin)
    DllCall("ole32.dll", "int", "CoInitialize", "ptr", 0)
    Local Const $WM_HTML_GETOBJECT = __IERegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT")
    Local Const $SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002
    Local $lResult, $typUUID, $aRet, $oIE
MsgBox(0, "msg", $WM_HTML_GETOBJECT)


    __IESendMessageTimeout($hWin, $WM_HTML_GETOBJECT, 0, 0, $SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, $lResult)

    $typUUID = DllStructCreate("int;short;short;byte[8]")
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 1, 0x626FC520)
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 2, 0xA41E)
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 3, 0x11CF)
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0xA7, 1)
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0x31, 2)
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0x0, 3)
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0xA0, 4)
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0xC9, 5)
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0x8, 6)
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0x26, 7)
    DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0x37, 8)


    MsgBox(0, "lResult", $lResult)


    $aRet = DllCall("oleacc.dll", "long", "ObjectFromLresult", "lresult", $lResult, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($typUUID), _
            "wparam", 0, "idispatch*", 0)
MsgBox(0, "aRet4", $aRet[4])
    If IsObj($aRet[4]) Then
        $oIE = $aRet[4] .Script()
        ; $oIE is now a valid IDispatch object
        Return $oIE.Document.parentwindow
    Else
        SetError(1)
        Return 0
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>__IEControlGetObjFromHWND
;===============================================================================
; Function Name:    __IERegisterWindowMessage()
; Description:      Required by __IEControlGetObjFromHWND()
; Author(s):        Larry with thanks to Valik
;===============================================================================
Func __IERegisterWindowMessage($sMsg)
    Local $aRet = DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "RegisterWindowMessage", "str", $sMsg)
    If @error Then Return SetError(@error, @extended, 0)
    Return $aRet[0]
EndFunc   ;==>__IERegisterWindowMessage

;===============================================================================
; Function Name:    __IESendMessageTimeout()
; Description:      Required by __IEControlGetObjFromHWND()
; Author(s):        Larry with thanks to Valik
;===============================================================================
Func __IESendMessageTimeout($hWnd, $msg, $wParam, $lParam, $nFlags, $nTimeout, ByRef $vOut, $r = 0, $t1 = "int", $t2 = "int")
    Local $aRet
    $aRet = DllCall("user32.dll", "long", "SendMessageTimeout", "hwnd", $hWnd, "int", $msg, $t1, $wParam, _
            $t2, $lParam, "int", $nFlags, "int", $nTimeout, "int*", "")
    If @error Then
        $vOut = 0
        Return SetError(@error, @extended, 0)
    EndIf
    $vOut = $aRet[7]    
    If $r >= 0 And $r <= 4 Then Return $aRet[$r]
    Return $aRet
EndFunc   ;==>__IESendMessageTimeout
```

My code so far:

```
def get_control_from_hwnd(hnd)  
    Win32API.new("ole32", "CoInitialize", ['P'] , 'I').call(0)

    reg_msg = Win32API.new("user32", "RegisterWindowMessage", ['P'] ,'I').call("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT")
    puts "msg: " + reg_msg.to_s
    result=" "*16 
    aInt = [0xA7, 0x31, 0x0, 0xA0, 0xC9, 0x8, 0x26, 0x37].pack 'I*'
    a = [0x626FC520, 0xA41E, 0x11CF, aInt].pack 'IIIP'

    sendMessagetimeout = Win32API.new("user32", "SendMessageTimeout", ['L','I','I','I','I','I','P'] , 'L')
    sendMessagetimeout.call(hnd.hex, reg_msg, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, result)

    puts "result unpacked: " + result.unpack("L").to_s  #i can confirm this is the same as the lResult from the autoit functioin

    idisp=0 
    #the problem is likely either here or the next line afterwards
    oIE = Win32API.new("oleacc", "ObjectFromLresult", ['P','P','I','P'] , 'L')

    oIE.call(result, a, 0, idisp)
    puts "idisp: " + idisp.to_s
    # returning zero
    puts idisp.unpack("L")  

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe we are doing the same, albeit I'm trying to do it in Perl. I dunno Ruby but looking at the script, it almost looks like similar to Perl. Take a look at this thread at autoIt, where I am still trying to tackle the issue http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=104894. But I think I might have gotten the idisp though. Two changes:

1) The way I am packing the struct is a bit different. My $iid looks like this:
pack('LSSC8',0x626FC520,0xA41E,0x11CF,0xA7,0x31,0x00,0xA0,0xC9,0x08,0x26,0x37). So in Ruby I guess it'd be [0x626FC520,0xA41E,0x11CF,0xA7,0x31,0x00,0xA0,0xC9,0x08,0x26,0x37].pack 'LSSC8'? I dunno the right syntax, but you get the idea.
2) I unpack the "result" from SendMessageTimeout & then pass it to ObjectFromLresult. If I pass the result directly, I get 0 as you were getting it.

But that is as far as I've gone.